# Como efetuar um console.log no map?

Tags: angular-6

Observe o algoritmo no Angular

```
findToOptions(searchValue: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.findAll(new PageParameters(15, 0, 'id,asc'), this.getSearch(searchValue),
      this.fields.toString(), true)
      .pipe(
        map(page => page.content)
      );
  }
```

Por favor, como faço para colocar um console.log nesse método?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa expandir sua *arrow function* para além de apenas uma expressão de tal forma que seja possível adicionar outras:

```
findToOptions(searchValue: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.findAll(new PageParameters(15, 0, 'id,asc'), this.getSearch(searchValue),
      this.fields.toString(), true)
      .pipe(
        map(page => {
            console.log('Sua mensagem aqui');
            return page.content;
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `{}` na sua `arrow function` para definir o escopo e coloque o console.log dentro dele.

Exemplo

```
{ 
    content.map( content => {
        console.log(content);
        return content.id
    })
}
```

---

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body).

> As arrow function podem ter um "escopo conciso" ou o "escopo de bloco"
>   usual.
>
> Em um escopo conciso, apenas uma expressão é necessária e um retorno
>   implícito é anexado.
>
> Em um escopo de bloco, você deve usar uma
>   instrução de retorno explícita.

Exemplo:

```
var func = x => x * x;
```

Conciso, portanto não necessita de um `return` implícito

```
var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; };
```

Esse bloco precisa de um `return` implícito pois não é conciso.

---

No seu exemplo você pode apenas adicionar `{}` e colocar um `console.log` antes

```
findToOptions(searchValue: string): Observable<any[]> {
return this.findAll(new PageParameters(15, 0, 'id,asc'), this.getSearch(searchValue),
  this.fields.toString(), true)
  .pipe(
    map(page => {
        console.log(page.content);
        return page.content;
    })
  );
```

}